# notepad++ (NppScript) how can i make a replace sctipt?

Tags: notepad++

I'm a noob and want to make a script in notepad++ that replace all lines beginning with a given character then remove all blank lines and put a new blank line before another given character and remove all blank spaces from each end of line.
Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

For example `character1= ;` `character2= [`

```
;aaaaaaaa
;aaaaaaaa
[bbbbb
ccc



;aaa

[bbb

ccc
```

I want to have

```
[bbbbb
ccc

[bbb
ccc
```

Now I have to use  replace > `^[;].*` to empty > remove empty lines > replace `[` in to `\n [`> replace  in to empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No needs for a script, a simple find and replace (using regex) works:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:;.*\R+|\R+|(\[.*\R))`
- Replace with: `(?1\n$1:)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  (?:           # non capture group
    ;.*\R+        # semicolon, 0 or more any character then a line break
   |            # OR
    \R+           # any kind of linebreak
   |            # OR
    (\[.*\R)      # group 1, opening square bracket, 0 or more any character then a line break
  )
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1             # if group 1 exists (there is a [ at the beginning of line)
    \n              # line feed (you may use \r\n for windows EOL)
    $1              # content of group 1 (the line that begins with [ )
  :             # else
                    # do nothing
)               # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]